# Spring JPA: Execute Specification of attribute Entity inside Specification parent

Tags: spring, jpa, specifications

I'm trying to build a Filter system for my Repository, the problem is i want my filter to be able to have a sub filter for entities inside my entity, so here is an example:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

 private String title;
 
 @ManyToOne
 private Autor autor;

}

@Entity
public class Autor {

 private String name;

}
```

That's a simplification of my current entities setup, then i'm trying to build this type of filter:

```
Specification<Autor> autorSpecification = ((root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
 return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(Autor_.name), "test");
});

Specification<Book> bookSpecification = (((root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
 Predicate bookPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(Book_.title), "title");
 Predicate autorPredicate = /* How i can turn my Autor specification into a predicate here */;
            
 return criteriaBuilder.and(bookPredicate, autorSpecification);
}));
```

That's where my problem is, i don't know how i can execute the Specification so i can have both filter, this is a simplified version of my system, each filter has a 'getSpecification', then the parent filter contains subFilters, and i would like to be able to execute those subFilters using the parent Specification.

I have tried different solutions but nothing worked so far:

```
//1
Predicate autorPredicate = autorSpecification.toPredicate(root.get(Book_.autor), query, criteriaBuilder);
//2
Predicate autorPredicate = autorSpecification.toPredicate(root.join(Book_.autor), query, criteriaBuilder);
```

I did also try to do it using a subQuery but i had no luck so far. Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

it should work this way :

`

```
Predicate bookPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(Book_.title), "title");

Predicate autorPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.join(Book_.autor).get(Autor_.name),"testname");

criteriaBuilder.and(bookPredicate, autorPredicate )
```

`